# Disable all warnings for specific file with premake5

Tags: premake

How can I instruct premake5 to disable all warnings from a specific file?

```
filter "files:my_file.c"
    warnings "Off"
```

does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
disablewarnings { "warning" }
```

Where `warning` is either the number or name of the compiler warning to disable.

From:

> https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/disablewarnings

[UPDATE]

If, however, it is a linker warning you want to suppress, then try this:

```
linkoptions { "-IGNORE:4221" }
```

Or whatever linker warning number you want to disable.

> https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/linkoptions

**UPDATE**: (2019.04.02) Corrected `linkoption` to `linkoptions` (Thanks @yuyoyuppe)

Comment: See github for examples of disablewarnings in use: https://github.com/search?l=Lua&q=disablewarnings&ref=opensearch&type=Code

Comment: fix: it's `linkoptions`

Comment: Thanks, @yuyoyuppe, I've edited it to avoid future confusion.